# If an element is in a set $A$, does this mean it is also an element of the indexed family of sets A?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathscr A=\{A_{\alpha}:\alpha \in \mathbb N =\{A_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in \mathbb N}$ be the indexed family of sets indexed by the set of natural numbers. Suppose $x\in A_{1}$. Does this mean $x\in \mathscr A$? If so, would this imply that $\mathscr A=\cup_{\alpha \in \mathbb N}A_{\alpha}$?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The elements of $\scr A$ are sets, namely the $A_\alpha$.

Comment: What about $\{x\}$? Would this be correct?: $x\in A_{1}\Rightarrow\{x\}\subseteq A_{1}$ and since $A_{1}\subseteq \mathscr A$ then $\{x\}\subseteq \mathscr A$.

Comment: You don't (in general) have $A_1 \subseteq \mathscr A$. Instead you have $A_1 \in \mathscr A$.